# Pager error in Kendo Grid(Nan-Nan of 1 items)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a Kendo grid with a list of student details. On click of the add button, the pager shows "Nan-Nan of 1 items".

```js
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Student.Models.StudentDetails>()
  .Name("StudentDetailsGrid")
  .Pageable()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { id="StudentDetailsGrid"})
  .Columns(col =>
    {
      col.Bound(a => a.FirstName).Title("Name");
      col.Bound(a => a.LastName).Hidden()
      col.Bound(a => a.StudentID).Hidden();
      col.Command(a => { a.Destroy(); a.Edit(); }).Title("");
    }
  )
  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar
    .Create()
    .Text("Add")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@id="btnCreateStudent"})
  )
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Scrollable(scrol => scrol.Enabled(true))
  .DataSource(source => source
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(5)
    .Model(a => {a.Id(b => b.StudentID);})
    .Read(read => read.Action()
    .Create(create => create.Action())
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action())
    .Update(update => update.Action())
  )
  .Events(even => even
    .Save("SaveDetails")
    .Edit("ChangeNoOfStudent")
    .DataBound("StudentValidate")
  )
)
```

on Document.ready function :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../Student/GetStudentDetails?StudentId=' + Data.StudentId,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    if (data.length > 0) {
        var studentdetail = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            pageSize: 5
        });
        $("#StudentDetailsGrid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(studentdetail);
    }
```

I have added the page size, but I can still see the "Nan-Nan of 1 items".

Can you please help?

Comment: I've had this problem before, you probably need to define a DataSource _model_ in "studentdetail"

Comment: Can you also post your Controller code ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to define the `pageSize` in the grid data source. Not in the success function.

In your case you only need to include in your data source the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../Student/GetStudentDetails?StudentId=' + Data.StudentId,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  pageSize: 10,
  success: function (data) {...
```

I hope this helps.
More information at: [Sudarsan Dash'blogs](http://sudarsandash.blogspot.com/2013/04/kendo-ui-grid-page-size-showing-nan-of.html)

Comment: In your example, the pageSize property isn't in the dataSource.

Answer (score 22):

I made it work like below: specifying the pagesize inside the datasource fixed my problem (Nan-Nan of 1 items)

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var modelData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({

      reorderable: true,
      pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
      },
      scrollable: true,
      sortable: true,
      dataSource: {
        data: modelData,
        pageSize: 10 // specifying the pagesize inside the datasource fixed my problem (Nan-Nan of 1 items)
      },
      columns: [{
        field: "fieldparameter",
        title: "titleparameter",
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true
      }]
    });
  }); < /script>
```

Comment: And note it is spelled, `pageSize`, not `pagesize`. Easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to resolve the issue. Works like a dream!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({

            dataSource: {
                pageSize: 10
            },

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `pageSize:5` inside of `dataSource:{}` as,

```json
dataSource: {
  pageSize: 5
}
```

If you put `pageSize: 5` outside of `dataSource:{}` you will get that error "Nan-Nan".

Comment: Was the case for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove .PageSize(5) from @(Html.Kendo().Grid()
Add pageSize: 5 in var studentdetail = new kendo.data.DataSource({

Comment: Please use code tags and also include an explanations to your answer

Comment: Kendo Pagesize will consider as NaN when you set it in the Grid and tries to bind it throgh jquery using DataSource. Hence just not assign PageSize in Grid declaration when using jquery datasource. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, simply adding `pageSize` to my `datasource` was not working for me.

I solved this problem by setting my initial grid page to 1, and my `pageSize` is also defined in my `datasource`:

```js
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: response.data });
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
grid.dataSource.page(1); // need so that Nan - Nan is not the starting page.
grid.dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you need to assign the pageSize property. The same if you need to re-assign the data source:

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   data: gridData,
   pageSize: 15 // this property
});
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```